# How to use downloaded version of andromda to create and compile Project?

Tags: maven, andromda

I am creating andromda project using following command
mvn org.andromda.maven.plugins:andromdapp-maven-plugin:3.4-SNAPSHOT:generate

This generates project using the latest version of andromda and using Web. I wish to create and compile andromda Project using downloaded andromda directory jars or binaries. Is it possible??? If yes then how??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this download the binaries of andromda version and run `mvn install` through command line in the main folder of downloaded andromda project. It will start to build and will put all the jars in maven repository. Now when generating the project you have to pass the version of the andromda whose binaries you have built. It will go directly to maven repo.